# Is it inappropriate to sign into my online college classes on my work computer?

Tags: work-time

So the last hour of work I’m always there alone, and there’s always nothing to do unless people come in or the phone rings.

Normally, I watch Netflix or Hulu but since I started my online college classes I wanted to use my laptop at work. Well then I found out there’s no WiFi at work so I can’t even use my laptop and I tried to do a personal hotspot on my phone but my phone plan doesn’t include that I guess.

So I thought about using the work computer for my classes but I just can’t decide if I should or not.

Comment: It's better than Hulu, but still... What does your manager think of the idea?

Comment: So you currently watch Netflix during work hours? How do you watch netflix if you have no wifi? Also, what is your current job about?

Comment: Yeah cause there’s nothing to do, I watch it on my phone because I have unlimited data. I’m a leasing agent. I haven’t spoken to my manager about it but she knows how slow it can get and she knows that my coworker and I are both on our phones when there’s nothing to do.

Comment: It seems like not a bad idea. If you have nothing to do, then spend the time learning. Especially if the skill you're learning is applicable to the job as well. If you're a programmer, constant learning is a must.

Answer (score 3):

> So I thought about using the work computer for my classes but I just can’t decide if I should or not.

Most likely that is something that is not allowed to do in your company.

In fact, using company resources for your personal use is also something that is not recommended (some places may be more permissive, but many are not).

I suggest you *check with your manager* if it is ok if you use your work computer for such things when you finish your daily tasks. Again, chances are that your manager may say no (perhaps he is willing but company policies forbid so), but you will never know if you don't ask.

Answer (score 1):

You ask your manager if this is Ok, as long as it doesn't interfere with your work. I wouldn't mention Netflix or Hulu at this point. If the manager allows it, you are fine. If he or she says "no", sorry, you lost.

Note that many places wouldn't mind in principle, but if you don't ask, and for some reason the company wants to get rid of you, that kind of thing is what they would use as an excuse. So it is much safer to ask.